# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'LoginManager.loginWithPermissions')

Tags: ios, react-native, facebook-sdk-4.x

Trying simple react-native app with facebook SDK, getting the following error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'LoginManager.loginWithPermissions')

Steps to reproduce:

react-native init app

react-native install react-native-fbsdk

react-native link react-native-fbsdk

Facebook guide https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/

react-native run-ios

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huEGT.png)

Any suggestions?

I think that react-native-fbsdk doesnt links with xcode project correctly...How to check it?
I don't have any exceptions while linking:

> 21:17 $ react-native link react-native-fbsdk
>   Scanning 559 folders for symlinks in /Users/denis/Projects/app/node_modules (7ms)

It looks like **libRCTFBSDK.a** is not included into the project, how to include it manually?

Comment: What version are you on?  Looks like there's a bug with linking in 0.6.1 https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/pull/349

Comment: Also, where is that error message coming from?  Cause there's a typo in `FBLoginManagerl.loginWithPermissions` and that might help you find the problem.  And that error doesn't match the screenshot you provided

Comment: @GarrettMcCullough i've tried 0.6.1 and 0.6.0

Comment: import FBSDK, { LoginManager } from 'react-native-fbsdk'

LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile']).then(...

Answer (score 7):

This solution helped me: https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app/issues/118#issuecomment-283670056

Download fb react native sdk and then drag ios/RCTFBSDK.xcodeproj to the Libraries group

Then add libRCTFBSDK to "Build Phases" -> "Link Binary With Libraries" (using the + button below)